# Blade Templates reusable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I came to laravel and I am having trouble with blade.

So I want to have my UI components reusable,  I don't want to copy and paste HTML.

```
 @include('blocks.js.modal', array(
                           'title'    => "{{ TextHelper::textLang('Guardar llamada','common') }}",
                           'close'    => "{{ TextHelper::textLang('Cerrar','common') }}",
                           'save'     => "{{ TextHelper::textLang('Guardar','common') }}"
                           )
      )
```

I pass a function helper to my partial template to use this variables but I can't manage to work

There's another way to do it, I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using blade syntax in PHP style array. Change Your code like so:

```
@include('blocks.js.modal', [
                       'title'    => TextHelper::textLang('Guardar llamada','common'),
                       'close'    => TextHelper::textLang('Cerrar','common'),
                       'save'     => TextHelper::textLang('Guardar','common')
                       ])
```

Comment: thanks I was trying TextHelper::textLang('Guardar llamada','common') between curly braces, that was my problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to give an array and call TextHelper in your Balde template:

```
@include('blocks.js.modal', array(
                       'title'    => ['Guardar llamada','common'],
                       'close'    => ['Cerrar','common'],
                       'save'     => ['Guardar','common']"
                       )
  )
```

Then you can call in Blade like this:

```
"{{ TextHelper::textLang($title[0],$title[1]}}"
```

Hope this may help you